# can any one help me on this from dumps?

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

View Exhibit 1 and examine the structure of the employees table :

```
desc employees
Name                           Null     Type
-------------------------------------------------
EMPLOYEE_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
FIRST_NAME                              VARCHAR2(20)
LAST_NAME                      NOT NULL CHAR(25)
EMAIL                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
PHONE_NUMBER                            VARCHAR2(20)
HIRE_DATE                      NOT NULL DATE
JOB_ID                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
SALARY                                  NUMBER(8,2)
COMMISSION_PCT                          NUMBER(2,2)
MANAGER_ID                              NUMBER(6)
DEPARTMENT_ID                           NUMBER(4)
```

View Exhibit 2 and examine the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increase
    (emp_num NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  inc_amt NUMBER;
  sal     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary INTO sal FROM employees WHERE employee_id = emp_num;

  inc_amt := sal*10;
  RETURN inc_amt;

END increase;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calc_sal IS
  emp_num NUMBER(7) := 120;
  amt     NUMBER    :=0;

  PROCEDURE raise_salary
    (emp_id NUMBER)
  IS
  BEGIN
    amt := increase(emp_num);

    UPDATE employees SET salary = salary+amt WHERE employee_id=emp_id;  
  END raise_salary;

BEGIN
  raise_salary(emp_num);
END calc_sal;
/
```

What is the outcome when the code is executed?

A.Both blocks compile and execute successfully when called.

B.Both blocks compile successfully but the CALC_SAL procedure gives an error on execution.

C.The CALC_SAL procedure gives an error on compilation because the amt variable should be declared in the RAISE_SALARY procedure.

D.The CALC_SAL procedure gives an error on compilation because the RAISE_SALARY procedure cannot call the stand-alone increase function.

I chose B because i compiled function and procedure and its compile sucssfully but I've tried to invoke(execute) procedure calc_sal and its give me error.

can you Explain to me what's the reason for this error and is my answer correct or false? because in dumps the answer was A

i invoke the procedure with this code :

```
begin
calc_sal;
end;
```

and the error i get :

```
Error report:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "HR.CALC_SAL", line 7
ORA-06512: at "HR.CALC_SAL", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 2
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

and employee_id column there is 107 employee Their numbers from 100 to 206.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis 
can you please If graciously Explain this Question

Comment: What error is produced?

Comment: And please edit your post and include the code you wrote to call CALC_SAL.  And what data is in the EMPLOYEES table for EMPLOYEE_ID = 120?  Thanks.

Comment: And for employee 120, what is the value in the SALARY column?

Comment: the salary for employee 120 = 8000 

@BobJarvis

Comment: In that case I can't explain why you get that error.  For employee 120 the `increase` routine should return 80,000 (nice raise!).  `raise_salary` will then compute the new salary as 88,000 and will store that into `EMPLOYEES.SALARY` for employee 120.  88,000 is well within the defined precision of `EMPLOYEES.SALARY`, which is NUMBER(8,2).  With minor changes I was able to [run this successfully on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbbac/8).  You'll need to debug it yourself as there may be an issue local to your site.  Best of luck.

Comment: so my answer is wrong ?

and the answer is A ?

@BobJarvis

Comment: What I found is that these routines [as I ran them on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbbac/8) run and complete normally and produce the expected results.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because querying an answer in a multiple choice test (certification crammer?) .  This is not a programming topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bob's comments state correctly, the code does work correctly, so the quiz answer **A** is defensible.

You're saying **B** because you get this error:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this
>   column

This is a data problem.  The function CALC_SAL() will succeed providing `SAL + SAL*10` is <= 999999.99, the maximum value which will fit into a column defined as `NUMBER(8,2)`.  So either your table is not defined the way you think it is, or the employee's original salary ishigher then you think it is.

Comment: thank you for explain @Bob Jarvis